# Convert an int to char16_t*

Tags: c++

I want to convert an `int` into a `char16_t*`:

```
char16_t* intToChar16(int input) {
    ...
    return output;
}
```

I'm new to C++. I tried to find a function to convert `int` to `char16_t*` but couldn't find it. How can I do it?

I want the input:

```
input myint = 3030;
```

to be converted into:

```
char16_t* output = u"3030";
```

Below this, the outer function expects a `char16_t*` as an argument.

Comment: Please be more specific. You want to reinterpret `int` as a pointer? Or your want to convert it to a string representation?

Comment: It would be easier to convert to a `std::u16string`. If you convert to a pointer that means you have to dynamically allocate the memory and manage the deletion of the same memory. A `std::u16string` will do that for you with no disadvantages.

Comment: For some specific "input" (value of `input`) what should the output (what the function returns) be?

Comment: I think the fact that the output is `char16_t` means that this is a conversion to string, rather than to binary. The output would be `uint16_t` if this was binary. But the OP should confirm what they want one way or another.

Comment: what will you do with the pointer after converting it?

Comment: Do you really need a pointer? Are you looking for this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring ? This might be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Please tell us what problem you are _actually_ trying to resolve.

Comment: The problem is the `char16_t*` requirement. Why do you need it? When and where and what for is the string supposed to be used? And does it really have to be a `char16_t`, not a `wchar_t`? If you're using it for the Windows Unicode API it uses UTF-16 encoded cjharacters using `wchar_t`. So for that please use `std::wstring` and related functions (like `std::to_wstring` as mentioned above), and use either its `c_str()` or `data()` function when you actually need the raw pointer.

Comment: Voting to reopen as the OP has improved the question.

Comment: @Galik I disagree there's no real _"improvement"_.

Comment: Does it have to be a _pointer_ to char16_t? Should it return `u"3030"` or `u"\u3030"`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use `std::to_string()` or `std::to_chars()` to convert an `int` to a regular string. We know that all characters of the result are going to be `'0'-'9'` or `'-'`, so simply character-by-character copying into your destination from the regular string should suffice as the conversion:

```
#include <string>

std::u16string intToChar16(const int i) {
    auto s = std::to_string(i);
    return {s.begin(), s.end()};
}
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
int myint = 3030;
auto output = intToChar16(myint);
// use output.data() wherever a char16_t* is needed ...
```

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/aMhMKE3b4